# How can I couple the lifetimes of two variables?

Tags: c++, scope, lifetime

The following code compiles and runs fine, but does not work as intended (compare the comments in the code). I believe the reason is that the lifetime of `is` ends with `getFileIter`, so the stream buffer iterator has nothing left to iterate over. (By contrast, I think I remember that in C#, `is` would live as long as the stream buffer iterator points to it, but that does not seem to be the case in C++.)

One fix to avoid this is using `... *is = new std::ifstream(p)`, but this means I have to take care of the pointer myself when I'm done.

Is there any mechanism to link the lifetimes of `is` and its stream buffer iterator?

```cpp
// g++ test.cpp -o test && ./test

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::istreambuf_iterator<char> getFileIter(std::string p)
{
  std::ifstream is(p);
  //std::ifstream *is = new std::ifstream(p);
  std::cout << "Read " << p << "? " << is.good() << std::endl;
  return std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is.rdbuf());
}

int main()
{
  std::string p1("/etc/passwd");
  std::string p2("/etc/group");

  // Prints 1 as if the two files were identical
  std::cout << std::equal(
    getFileIter(p1),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
    getFileIter(p2)
  ) << std::endl;

  // Prints nothing except /////
  auto x = getFileIter(p1);
  int i = 0;
  do
  {
    std::cout << *(x++) << "/";
    i++;
  } while (i < 5);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Encapsulate your stream and iterator into a class that gets returned.

Comment: You can implement wrapper class, which will behave same as shared_ptr for files, but will increase reference count when iterator is obtained for the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one comment suggests, combine both things: stream and its iterator in a struct - to ensure the iterator will not outlive the stream:

```
struct FileIter
{
    FileIter(const std::string& p) 
        : is(p), iter(is.rdbuf())
    {}
    std::ifstream is;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter;
};

std::cout << std::equal(
    FileIter(p1).iter,
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
    FileIter(p2).iter
) << std::endl;

FileIter x(p1);
int i = 0;
do
{
    std::cout << *(x.iter++) << "/";
    i++;
} while (i < 5);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

If you like -- you might make this `FileIter` looks like iterator - see this [post](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp)

Two important things:

In this code:

```
std::cout << std::equal(
    FileIter(p1).iter,
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
    FileIter(p2).iter
) << std::endl;
```

`FileIter` might be temporary (nameless) because its lifetime is guaranteed to be as long as to the end of expression (the semicolon).

Here, you cannot replace `FileIter x(p1);` with `auto x = FileIter(p1).iter;` because stream in `FileIter` will end its lifetime with the end of expression (semicolon here).

```
FileIter x(p1);
int i = 0;
do
{
    std::cout << *(x.iter++) << "/";
    i++;
} while (i < 5);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is perfect. I was initially opposed to the idea of introducing another class (see my edited answer if you want to know why), but I now see that I don't even need the function with your approach, and my code is actually a lot cleaner this way. Thanks!

Comment: *"you cannot replace `FileIter x(p1);` with `auto x = FileIter(p1).iter;`"*. But with [lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) (from sub-object), `auto&& x = FileIter(p1).iter;` would be possible.

Comment: I'd recommend to go even further with the wrapper, adding wrapper methods for the iterator so that the return value could be a drop in replacement. Depending on OP's use case, that may be overkill.